# How to bind click event after page is fully loaded

Tags: vue.js

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  }
  methods: {
    addToList () {
      this.list.push( // some object )
    },
    clickDiv() {
      console.log('click div!!!')
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
 <button @click="addToList">button</button>
    <div
      v-for(item, index) in list
      :key="index"
      @click="clickDiv"
    >
      {{ item.text }}
    </div>
```

I click the button. Then, some object is added to 'list'  and re-render divs. 
Howerver, click event is not working. I guess, the reason is,,  I tried to bind event after the page is fully loaded. Is there any way to bind the event???

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma(",") after the data property. Try again after adding it.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  }, <===== Here.
  methods: {
    addToList () {
      this.list.push( // some object )
    },
    clickDiv() {
      console.log('click div!!!')
    }
  }
}
```